# Как "научить" HTML брать контент из JSON файла?

Tags: javascript, html, json, handlebars

Мне нужно чтобы HTML сайта использовал mustache или handlebars чтобы заполнить себя контентом из JSON файла.

Я создал простой HTML template и наполнил его контентом из внешнего JS файла. http://codepen.io/MaxVelichkin/pen/qNgxpB (образец ниже не работает, т.к к нему не подключена библиотека handlebars)

```js
var quoteInfo = document.getElementById("quote-template").innerHTML;
var template = Handlebars.compile(quoteInfo);
var quoteData = template ({
    name: "Someome",
    quotes: [
    {quote: "Some quote-1"},
    {quote: "Some quote-2"},
    {quote: "Some quote-3"},
    {quote: "Some quote-4"}
    ],
})

document.getElementById('quoteData').innerHTML += quoteData;
```

```html
<div id="quoteData"></div>

<script id="quote-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">

<h3>Favorite {{name}} Quotes </h3>
<ol>
{{#each quotes}}
<li>{{quote}}
{{/each}}
</ol>
</script>
```

Теперь мне нужно чтобы контент лежал изначально в JSON файле.
Правильно ли я понимаю дальнейшую логику (ниже), и как решить эти две проблемы, решающие главную - научить html брать контент из JSON файла?

1. Нужно чтобы JSON передал контент в HTML, но этот контент должен быть преобразован в Javascript. Для этого в JSON файле я прописываю тот же код что и в .Javascript файле в моем примере по ссылке выше, но перед последней строчкой (которая помещает контент в HTML через innerHTML) пишу: var contentJS = JSON.parse(quoteData); и в последней строчке заменяю последнее qoteData на contentJS.
2. Подключаю JSON к HTMLПока не нашел понятный мне способ как это сделать. Насколько я понимаю, именно это делает предложенный мне Fetch API код:

`fetch('/api/jsondata')
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(data => el.innerHTML(Handlebars.compile(data)))
  .catch(err => throw err)`

Пока не онимаю как его использовать, насколько я понимаю Fetch чем-то похож на XMLHttpRequest (XHR) (что для меня - совсем новая тема)...

Comment: JSON в HTML можно писать либо на сервере, либо грузить с помощью AJAX (как вы это сделали через `fetch`). Других способов пока не существует.

Comment: @Umer Не подскажите, как именно это можно сделать на сервере? Я сейчас изучаю Node.js, и уже установил локальный сервер, могу открыть тестовую веб-страницу по адресу localhost:8080

Answer (score 2):

Простой сервер на node, который встроит JSON в страницу

```js
const http = require('http');
const server = http.createServer().listen(8080);

server.on('request', (req, res) => {
  res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html;charset=utf-8' });
  //Твой JSON
  const data = {
    name: "Someome",
    quotes: [
      {quote: "Some quote-1"},
      {quote: "Some quote-2"},
      {quote: "Some quote-3"},
      {quote: "Some quote-4"}
    ],
  };
  const jsonString = JSON.stringify(data);
  res.end(`
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <script>
    var quoteData =  ${jsonString}
  </script>
</body>
</html>
    `)
});
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Если можно, объясните пожалуйста процесс на пальцах для новичка. Правильно ли я понял, что код выше комментария "Твой JSON" нужно поместить в package.json, который автоматом создается при установке сервера через команду npm install http-server? Код ниже нужно поместить в JSON, который я уже вручную создам для контента страницы, скажем content.json? Как (и где) прописать путь к нему чтобы код в package.json использовал его content.json? Этот способ задействует handlebars templates?

Comment: Насколько я понял, этот способ создает всю html разметку вместе с контентом, как подгрузить только необходимый контент, скажем в дивы с определенным id?

Comment: Если способ с AJAX проще, не могли бы вы описать его (если можно - какой код в каком файле должен быть и как они слинкованы). Извините за большое количество вопросов и спасибо!

Comment: @MaximVelichkin, вопросов действительно много и я не думаю, что они укладываются в рамки топика, поэтому советую Вам ознакомиться с материалом этого сайта - http://www.nodebeginner.ru/, он поможет Вам в ознакомлении с клиент-серверной архитектурой.